# are these functions for open address hashing, proper?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hash-tables

I want to use these two functions in two hash-tables with open-addressing. Is there any problems with these functions? If yes, why they are not appropriate?

```
H(k,i) = (k mod m + 3i mod m) mod m

H(k,i) = (k^2 + 2k + i(k mod m)) mod m
```

Comment: Something is missing in your second equation.  Please proof-read your question and edit it to correct issues.

Comment: Did you test them?

Comment: @Pseudonym No. I haven't implemented the Hash.

Comment: You should test it on some data set which is representative of the expected key distribution.